# Find out IP address associated with MAC Address in servlet web application

Tags: java, servlets, networking

I'm  trying to find out the **IP** address associated with an **MAC** address in servlet programming. Is it possible ?

I have the MAC address. Using MAC address how can I find out the IP Address ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to retrieve an IP address by knowing the MAC address..

Comment: ok But any idea about dynamic ip Address. when ip change dynamically then how can determine old ip?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you are in a `Servlet`, you can get the IP of the client with `request.getRemoteAddr()` and since it seems that you already have the Mac address... that's it.

As simple as that... if the the Mac address that you have is effectively the one of the client making the request (which isn't very clear in your question).

Comment: i want to retrieve IP address with the help of  MAC Address . is it possible? also give me some idea regarding that.

Comment: *in servlet programming*  <-- what do you mean ? (as far as I understand it means : in the context of a request-response loop)

Comment: Hello ben75 it's possible to get ip using mac.in my case i have some mac addresses,i want to get ip address related to that mac address. so can you tell me any good way..from 2 days i facing this stuck...

Answer (score 0):

A MAC address doesn't have a unique IP address, only one one within the subnet the MAC address appears in. Your question therefore diesnt really make sense.

The question also arises how you're getting this MAC address in the first place, and why, and what uses you intend to put it to. You need to understand that MAC addresses can be changed by the user, or his net admin, and aren't usable as unique system identifiers.